# CSS issue with overflow-y

Tags: html, css

I have a video player on my site which will have a list of videos on the right hand side. This list will keep growing over time and thus comes the need to have `overflow-y: scroll;` added to my CSS.

But at the same time, I have a nifty little hover effect which adds an arrow while hovering and once you have clicked.

The problem is, when I add `overflow-y: scroll;` to the container, it removes my arrow effect, does anybody know how I can keep the scroll effect and the arrow at the same time?

Please see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ue5tW/3/) for an example.

You will notice I have added a comment where I think the overflow should be added, but I might be mistaken:

```
/*THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD OVERFLOW-Y SCROLL*/
#My-Vids #videos .list ul {
    background-color:#004461;

    height:482px;
    margin:20px
}
```

**EDIT:** to see what happens, just place `overflow-y: scroll;` into my code.

Comment: The scrollbar is pushing the sidebar over to the left, so you need to remove some of the right margin/padding to get the arrow to show again.

Comment: @TylerH - I literally just figured that out myself now! Lol.. would be the last thing I try after posting here. I feel ashamed! HAHA.. Thanks you though.

Comment: no worries. If you *are* truly ashamed, though, you do have the ability to delete your own question :-P

Comment: Maybe someone else will be an idiot one day and this post will help them ;) haha

Comment: You should put a semicolon `;` at the end of each statements. 2337 semicolons are missing...

Comment: @AndreaLigios ? He has semicolons at the end of all of his statements already.

Comment: @TylerH: look better. Almost every last statement misses a semicolon. This is a bad practice because you need to remember to add it if you add a new rule for that selector... a nightmare. For free. :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios Semicolons on the last property of a selector is not required in CSS. So they are not "missing", and the code will be interpreted fine (read: correctly) by browsers. "Missing" is different from what you think is "bad practice" :-)

Comment: @TylerH I know they're not required, and I wasn't (obviously) answering the question, just suggesting through a comment that *You **should** put a semicolon at the end of each statement*. Regardless of what I think, this *is* a bad practice, that everyone knows, so why whining against the recommendation of avoiding it ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a few things:

- Remove the `margin-left` on your list
- Add `padding-left` to match the original amount
- Remove the background colour from the list
- Apply that background colour to the list items instead
- Change your list header `<p>` elements to use `padding` instead of `margin`.

The end result is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ue5tW/4/), which I believe is the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks Niet, I figured it out shortly after posting! One of those blonde moments. But Ill give it to you anyways. :)